# JavaFX ListView Scroll thumb issue

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I am facing a problem while implementing a lazy loaded ListView, wherein I stop populating the ListView with items once the scrollbar is visible. The ListView items are then added when the user scrolls to the bottom of the list.

The issue is that the scrollbar max limit while scrolling is not the same as while dragging the thumb via the mouse. So while scrolling via the mouse the ListView is never populated with new items as it never reaches the bottom of the list.

Below is a code snippet for populating the view:

```
private void refreshView() {
    refreshingView = true;
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (thumbnailListView == null) {
                    Platform.runLater(this);
                    return;
                }
                thumbnailLayoutModelObservableList.clear();
                thumbnailLayoutModelObservableList.addAll(filterThumbnails(thumbnailLayoutModels));
                if(CURRENT_SORT==ThumbnailSortOrder.DESC) {
                    thumbnailLayoutModelSortedList.setComparator(thumbnailDateComparator.reversed());
                } else {
                    thumbnailLayoutModelSortedList.setComparator(thumbnailDateComparator);
                }

                newThumbQueue.removeAll(thumbnailLayoutModelObservableList);

                updateCounts();

                if(!scrollListenerAttached) {
                    ScrollBar scrollBar = getListViewScrollBar();
                    if (scrollBar != null) {
                        scrollBar.valueProperty().addListener(scrollChangeListener);
                        scrollListenerAttached=true;
                    }
                }
                checkIfUIUpdateLock();
                refreshingView = false;
            }catch(Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error refreshing view",e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The checkIfUIUpdateLock() lock method is as below:

```
private void checkIfUIUpdateLock() {
    ScrollBar scrollBar = getListViewScrollBar();
    if (scrollBar != null && scrollBar.isVisible()) {
        double position = scrollBar.getValue();
        if(CURRENT_SORT == ThumbnailSortOrder.ASC) {
            if(position != scrollBar.getMax()) {
                pauseUIScroll = true;

            }
            else {
                pauseUIScroll = false;
            }
        } else if(CURRENT_SORT == ThumbnailSortOrder.DESC) {
            if(position != scrollBar.getMin()) {
                pauseUIScroll = true;

            }
            else {
                pauseUIScroll = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The pauseUIScroll boolean controls the addition of elements to the ListView.

Is there any way to make the ListView recalculate the scrollbar bounds? I tried using refresh() and requestLayout() but it doesn't fix the scrollbar.

## EDIT

I did some debugging and noticed that the max value returned by the scrollbar.getMax() is a number greater than 1 whereas the scrollbar only scrolls to a max value of 1 via the mouse scroll. Is this a possible bug in JavaFX?

Comment: The `ListView` is already optimised to handle lots a data appropriately. What's the purpose of creating a "lazy loading" implementation?

Comment: @Sedrick the lazy load is to prevent the viewport from flickering everytime new elements are added to it. I have a custom list cell containing image groups which in turn contain thumbnails. The addition to the ListView causes the viewport to flicker/redraw.